# Unable to add List to other list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two list defined as

```
List<List<int>> thirdLevel = new List<List<int>>();
List<List<int>> fourthLevel = new List<List<int>>();
```

Here the type of both the list are same.
I want to add contents of 1 list to other. Just want to make a duplicate of that list. I am unable to add 1 list in other.

I tried using:

```
thirdLevel.Add(fourthLevel);
```

But I am getting error only.The error states that the overloaded method of `Add(int)` has some invalid arguments. I don't know what should I try. Can't I add a list in this way?

Can you just guide me, how should I add One list to other, if I have defined the list inside a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound like you need [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) instead of `Add` if you add a list of items into another list:

```
 thirdLevel.AddRange(fourthLevel);
```